# Hadoop namenode format: No KeyProvider found

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I'm trying to install Hadoop on Ubuntu. I've followed this tutorial: http://dogdogfish.com/2014/04/26/installing-hadoop-2-4-on-ubuntu-14-04/ and all seems to work fine.
But, when I run the command:

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

I get the following INFOs:

```
14/12/26 18:18:21 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
14/12/26 18:18:21 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
14/12/26 18:18:22 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Formatting using clusterid: CID-b144d870-a74f-4c1c-8918-5b2fcef6805c
14/12/26 18:18:23 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: No KeyProvider found.
```

After the *"No KeyProvider found"*, the process is completly stuck and there is no output.

Have you got any idea about what is the problem or how investigate it?
Thank you in advance.

Edited: the jstack result

```
2014-12-27 17:14:53
Full thread dump OpenJDK Zero VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x70104060 nid=0xe88 waiting on condition [0x00000000]


 java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb577e3c0 nid=0xd98 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb577c9b8 nid=0xd97 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb5769fd8 nid=0xd96 in Object.wait() [0x7045e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x859e6a70> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x859e6a70> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb5768a80 nid=0xd95 in Object.wait() [0x705fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x859e6b00> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x859e6b00> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"main" prio=10 tid=0xb570c4b0 nid=0xd93 runnable [0xb59a5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$12.setBits(CharMatcher.java:507)
    at com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or.setBits(CharMatcher.java:642)
    at com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.precomputedInternal(CharMatcher.java:673)
    at com.google.common.base.Platform.precomputeCharMatcher(Platform.java:53)
    at com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.precomputed(CharMatcher.java:657)
    at com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.<clinit>(CharMatcher.java:179)
    at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoCodec.getCodecClasses(CryptoCodec.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoCodec.getInstance(CryptoCodec.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoCodec.getInstance(CryptoCodec.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:755)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:934)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1504)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0xb5766130 nid=0xd94 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0xb5780058 nid=0xd99 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 355
```

Comment: The KeyProvider message should be innocuous. Recently, hadoop added encryption at rest as a new feature. The log just means no KeyProvider for this feature was configured but it is not necessary if you don't use the feature. Can you post a jstack of the namenode process to see where it gets stuck? Also, are the permissions to the namenode data dir set properly for the namenode to write to it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I added the jstack result in my post. The permission to the data directory is set to "Create and delete files" for "Hadoop" owner and "Access files" to "Hadoop" group.

Comment: My guess is that this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392531/namenode-appears-to-hang-on-start where CharMatcher#setBits hangs. The asker upgraded guava to get past the hang. Perhaps that will work for you?

Comment: Your have been very helpful. It works, now. If you edit your comment as an answer, I will quote it. Thank you.